# what happen if i have the same route as path alias?

Tags: routes, path-aliases

What if I have the following route in a custom module and a path alias that is equal to the route path?

```
mymodule.contact:
path: /contact
defaults:
    _controller: Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyController::contact
requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, the alias gets priority. or maybe it was the other way around. What have you found?

Comment: I searched for it i didn't find any answer ! I think you are right aliases are called first

Comment: I had this same issue yesterday - aliases get called first.

Answer (score 0):

The alias gets priority over the route.

Comment: This was the question "What if I have the following route in a custom module and a path alias that is equal to the route path?"
The answer is what I said, the alias takes priority over the route. Even the comments of the OP say exactly that. I don't know how this doesn't provide an answer.

Comment: To be an answer, it lacks references. May you point out where exactly the documentation says a path alias has priority over a module route? If you understood that looking at the Drupal core code, may you show the code that is taking care of routes / path aliases resolution?

Comment: What about if neither is the case. I cannot point to the code and there is no documentation that says it. But I have done exactly this. I have created a route and a path alias with the same value and the alias takes priority. Are you saying that because I have personal experience, and not official Drupal documentation, with this that I shouldn't answer the question?